# Annabelle with Missile High Explosive

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, mods

How can I use those two things together, Annabelle(Missile Launcher) can use High Velocity Missiles, but cant use the High Explosive. Is there any way to make it use those too? Will it work with regular Missile Launcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use High Explosive missiles with Annabelle without issue... and you should certainly be able to use them with any other missile launcher as well.

Comment: but I cant, even if i throw away the other missiles. I cant equp them and it just doesnt work. it might be a bug, but i thought that maybe i need some mod.